# no screenshare option in openmeeting

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openmeetings

I have installed latest version of openmeeting on ubuntu 18
started the startup.sh
trying to connect with browser : xx:port : ok
I start a public presentation room
I get the whiteboard, but can not find screen sharing option
do we need to install additional package for this ?
thanks for all info/help
best regards, Guy

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of OpenMeetings devs

The icon for screen-sharing is upper-right corner.

You should have running KMS, otherwise audio/video/screen-sharing will not be accessible

Comment: thanks for the update, but : the installation guide/procedure needs some work - it is not very clear any distributed over different locations.   even when following the kms procedure, you get some error when importing the key and again this is documented on different location..  finally could install kms and started the service -- now when opening the presentation room I see the icon for sharing...     Now running first test with users..    best regards, Guy

Comment: Lots of detailed instructions are here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OPENMEETINGS/Tutorials+for+installing+OpenMeetings+and+Tools

Answer (score 0):

as suggested : kms should be installed and running - follow steps on https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html